# Cambio de tipo de dato en Oracle 11G de MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY a SDE.ST_GEOMETRY

Tags: stored-procedure, oracle-11g, arcgis

estoy trabajando con ArcGis 9.3 y 10.5 y estoy en proceso de migración de datos de una tabla a otra a través de DBLINK y mediante un procedimiento almacenado y al hacer una migración en específico me aparece el error de tipo de dato esperado haciendo alusión a estos registros.

[image: Migración de una tabla a otra]

Alguien sabe como realizar algún tipo de parseo o si existe un código de procedimiento o algo similar? Lo agradezco de corazón!

Comment: He visto que también se ocupan procedimientos de ArcGis que lo mas seguro estén en Pyton, de ser así igual me sirven las respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me respondo mi pregunta dado que ArcGis 9.3 (yo ocupé esta versión), posee una herramienta de migración de datos que se llama "Migrate Storage", la cual ofrece de una manera fácil el cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna antes seleccionada.

[image: Migrate Storage]

De la siguiente manera uno selecciona una geodatabase **previamente registrada** y se conecta para ponerla como un **input dataset**, luego uno selecciona el **configuration keyword** o palabra clave de configuración y pone siguiente. Luego de esto el programa automáticamente realiza la migración de los datos de un tipo a otro.

Gracias!